# Optaplanner shadow variable corruption check mechanism

Tags: optaplanner

I'm having score corruption exception with construction heuristic phase with FULL_ASSERT:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption: the
>   entity (Task{6661-30})'s shadow variable (Task.plannedDateTime)'s
>   corrupted value (null) changed to uncorrupted value (2018-06-04T07:00)
>   after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the
>   genuine variables. Maybe the VariableListener class
>   (VrpTaskStartTimeListener) for that shadow variable
>   (Task.plannedDateTime) forgot to update it when one of its sources
>   changed after completedAction (Task{6661-30} {Shift{Tech1:2018-06-04}
>   -> Shift{Tech1:2018-06-04}}).
>
> at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:462)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(DefaultSolverScope.java:140)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractPhaseScope.java:171)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.AbstractPhase.predictWorkingStepScore(AbstractPhase.java:169)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.doStep(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:108)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:95)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:173)
>     at...

Now while looking at DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.doStep , it does:

```
private void doStep(ConstructionHeuristicStepScope<Solution_> stepScope) {
        Move<Solution_> nextStep = stepScope.getStep();
        nextStep.doMove(stepScope.getScoreDirector()); //Step-1
        predictWorkingStepScore(stepScope, nextStep);
        ...
    }
```

`predictWorkingStepScore()` calls `AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale()` and `assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale()` is:

```
    public void assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(Score expectedWorkingScore, Object completedAction) {
                SolutionDescriptor<Solution_> solutionDescriptor = getSolutionDescriptor();
    //Step2
                Map<Object, Map<ShadowVariableDescriptor, Object>> entityToShadowVariableValuesMap = new IdentityHashMap<>();
                ...
                    entityToShadowVariableValuesMap.put(entity, shadowVariableValuesMap);
                }
//Step3
                variableListenerSupport.triggerAllVariableListeners();
                for (Iterator<Object> it = solutionDescriptor.extractAllEntitiesIterator(workingSolution); it.hasNext();) {
                    Object entity = it.next();
                    EntityDescriptor<Solution_> entityDescriptor
                            = solutionDescriptor.findEntityDescriptorOrFail(entity.getClass());
                    Collection<ShadowVariableDescriptor<Solution_>> shadowVariableDescriptors = entityDescriptor.getShadowVariableDescriptors();
                    Map<ShadowVariableDescriptor, Object> shadowVariableValuesMap = entityToShadowVariableValuesMap.get(entity);
                    for (ShadowVariableDescriptor shadowVariableDescriptor : shadowVariableDescriptors) {
                        Object newValue = shadowVariableDescriptor.getValue(entity);
                        Object originalValue = shadowVariableValuesMap.get(shadowVariableDescriptor);
    //Step4
                        if (!Objects.equals(originalValue, newValue)) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(VariableListener.class.getSimpleName() + " corruption:"

        }
        }
```

Here's the description, which I believe:

- Step 1: execute step's move (it also executes shadow var listeners)
- Step 2: get current entities shadow vars values.(Here shadow vars
  wont have valid value)
- Step 3: execute ShadowsVariable listehttp://example.comners(now
  shadows will have right values)
- Step 4: Get new values and compare
  with Step2.

Now, the problem is for a custom listener on a genuine variable, here is the order:

1. Inverse relation shadow variable listener
2. Custom listener
3. Anchor shadow variable

What can I do to make above order such that custom listener executes last?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the `sources` attribute of `@CustomShadowVariable` correctly.

There is this guarantee:
[image]

Comment: @Geffrey, IRSV,custom var, ASV all listen on same genuine variable.

Comment: Then there is no order guarantee between them. To change that, have one of them depend on one of the others too.